# Is Nvidia Geforce GT 630M 2GB is compatible for tensorflow-gpu?

Tags: nvidia

I am a beginner in Deep Learning. I have a doubt that whether my graphics card 
(Geforce GT630M 2GB) supports tensorflow-gpu or not. If so which version of tensorflow-gpu, CUDA, and cuDNN are suitable? My system specs are Windows 10 Pro - 64bit, Intel i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz, 8GB RAM, python 3.6(pip environment).
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

No, TenserFlow needs
[NVIDIA® GPU card with CUDA® Compute Capability 3.5 or higher](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#hardware_requirements).
But your GPU only has a CUDA® Compute Capability of 2.1 GeForce GT 630M (see this [list](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)).